# AIR add Menu to chromless application

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I have an air chromless application.
On mac OS, it's very easy to create an application menu with

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.menu = rootMenu;
```

But on Windows OS, as I try to do that with

```
stage.nativeWindow.menu = rootMenu;
```

An error appear : NativeMenu only works with chrom application.

Can you help me to found a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's strange that you are using different code. Try to do

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.activeWindow.menu = rootMenu
```

that should work on Windows